Rendering outliers in Gnuplot's box-and-whiskers
A boxplot in Gnuplot v5.4.2 renders as shown below. Is there a way to "project" all outliers belonging to the same box to the same x-position above / below the box?
The drawing is somewhat ugly, and I know I can use nooutliers or
set style boxplot fraction 1

so no outliers are drawn and the whiskers extend to 0% resp 100%. (though IIUC, nooutliers wouls affect mean and other stats properties).
Is there some point-type that has zero x-width so that all outlers with the same y are plotted at the same x-coodinate?
I read "set style boxplot" documentation at http://www.gnuplot.info/docs/loc15545.html and there is no indication of how to do it. I also found How to group boxplot outliers in gnuplot but it is from 9 years ago, very complicated and only applies to a 1-file setting.

Years ago I used GNU R for similar plots, maybe that's worth a try?

Edit
Here is a script that reproduces it on v5.4.2. The final script has many boxes; the boxes will get narrower but the outliers still spread.
FILS = " x.data"
FUNS = " atan2f"
COLS = " 1"
YOFFS = " 0"
FARBEN = " white"
WBOX = 0.5

set title  "..."
set ylabel "..."

set style data boxplot
set style fill solid 0.5 border -1
set style boxplot # fraction 0.95
# set style boxplot outliers pointtype 7 # pointsize 0 won't work

set key noautotitle

N = words(FUNS)
File(i) = word(FILS, i)
Col(i) = 0 + word(COLS, i) # "+0" casts from string to number
Yoff(i) = 0 + word(YOFFS, i)
Farb(i) = word(FARBEN, i)

array MEANS[N] # set array size
do for [i=1:N] {
    stats File(i) u (Yoff(i) + column(Col(i))) nooutput
    MEANS[i] = STATS_mean
}
       
unset xtics
set xtics format " " scale 0
set xrange[1 - WBOX : N + WBOX]
#set yrange[-0.3 + * : *]

set for [i=1:N] xtics add (word(FUNS,i) i)

plot for [i=1:N] File(i) u (i):(Yoff(i) + column(Col(i))) \
      w boxplot lt rgb Farb(i) \
    , MEANS u ($0+1-WBOX/2):2:(WBOX):(0) w vec dt 2 lc "black" nohead ti "mean value"

pause -1

x.data
2806
2812
2825
2849
2901
2840
2894
2923
2944
2879
2977
2939
3068
3016
3018
2994
2891
1629
2873
2997
3018
3034
3053
2939
2986
2912
2944
2918
2891
2840
2883
2861
2825
2812
2797
2887
2816
2887
2819
2815
2841
2864
2818
2848
2898
2944
2871
2963
2896
3005
3017
2981
2989
2837
1629
2852
2986
2981
2993
3008
2896
2966
2871
2944
2891
2860
2818
2852
2827
2815
2803
2836
2816
2819
2815
2887
2847
2849
2862
2885
2858
2898
2956
2884
2944
3016
3006
2986
3093
3015
2862
1629
2928
3087
3093
3058
2952
3016
2890
2950
2956
2848
2813
2885
2805
2794
2847
2836
2812
2819
2821
2818
2843
2887
2822
2836
2855
2896
2829
2894
2913
2889
2983
2940
3050
3048
3073
2902
1629
2914
3079
3048
3056
2939
2983
2896
2940
2894
2828
2905
2855
2812
2812
2887
2836
2816
2821
2859
2844
2845
2821
2887
2830
2818
2853
2910
2857
2909
2944
2923
2998
3033
3062
3054
2893
1629
2872
3045
3062
3031
2977
2923
2953
2902
2857
2898
2855
2818
2828
2830
2821
2860
2844
2859
2904
2867
2869
2839
2833
2887
2803
2827
2858
2817
2880
2943
2862
2981
2982
3016
3016
2838
1629
2826
3007
3016
2995
2980
2862
2934
2895
2817
2865
2809
2803
2839
2815
2839
2847
2850
2904
2843
2814
2888
2858
2828
2813
2887
2818
2831
2822
2829
2914
2944
2931
2948
3040
3021
2882
1629
2879
3015
3040
2933
2949
2944
2917
2834
2822
2821
2818
2887
2809
2837
2858
2903
2817
2843
2901
2851
2868
2903
2849
2830
2821
2887
2818
2844
2889
2846
2919
2906
2989
3041
3074
2951
1629
2963
3074
3041
2986
2885
2919
2857
2913
2844
2815
2836
2821
2815
2852
2903
2858
2854
2901
2926
2897
2905
2825
2917
2865
2827
2821
2887
2812
2855
2805
2888
2884
2989
2993
3042
3001
1629
3010
3057
2993
2986
2960
2888
2811
2858
2812
2839
2818
2827
2849
2910
2825
2908
2909
2926
2947
2940
2959
2897
2860
2820
2825
2847
2815
2887
2803
2849
2840
2926
2894
2939
3016
2991
1629
2997
3013
2939
2912
2918
2840
2850
2812
2887
2825
2829
2825
2815
2855
2897
2954
2940
2947
2880
2874
2891
2916
2908
2883
2825
2892
2858
2806
2887
2783
2835
2910
2881
2965
2983
3012
1629
3084
3049
2965
2960
2847
2835
2803
2836
2806
2853
2895
2825
2880
2917
2916
2881
2883
2880
2976
2962
2943
2896
2947
2946
2917
2845
2808
2859
2779
2887
2818
2907
2917
2923
3033
3054
1629
3045
3024
2923
2902
2898
2818
2834
2860
2859
2821
2854
2917
2947
2881
2896
2948
2952
2976
2934
2891
3012
2978
2919
2865
2947
2929
2891
2843
2831
2828
2887
2809
2843
2944
2948
3018
1629
3015
2942
2944
2834
2821
2887
2827
2903
2843
2906
2931
2947
2880
2915
2978
3008
2889
2934
3063
3000
3001
2928
2993
2972
2930
2901
2891
2929
2913
2910
2812
2887
2859
2900
2977
3033
1629
3048
2977
2900
2861
2831
2812
2916
2908
2929
2875
2883
2930
2984
3002
2928
3001
2988
3063
3017
3012
2985
3045
3022
2977
2943
2984
2978
2889
2884
2920
2846
2858
2887
2834
2944
2983
1629
3046
2944
2834
2834
2855
2846
2923
2878
2889
2979
2988
2943
2978
3016
3045
2972
2998
3017
3017
2976
3088
3043
3057
3011
3035
3036
2988
2934
2960
2919
2947
2910
2844
2887
2843
2927
1629
2942
2823
2887
2903
2906
2947
2924
3008
2934
2991
3051
3035
3008
3060
3043
3093
2974
3017
2995
2984
3010
3069
3049
3011
3016
3063
3043
3017
2984
3022
2943
2966
2947
2846
2887
2887
1629
2944
2830
2846
2878
2979
2943
3035
2972
3017
3034
3066
3016
3014
3044
3069
3007
2969
2995
2886
2832
2851
2903
2894
2833
2877
2952
2990
2986
3001
3055
3007
3029
2979
2922
2890
2887
1629
2821
2872
2922
2972
3037
3007
3043
3001
2986
3002
2965
2877
2818
2885
2903
2842
2841
2886
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
61
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
2874
2847
2929
2907
2861
2821
2874
2952
3005
2990
3079
3046
3010
3037
3047
2935
2937
2708
1535
2777
2939
2935
3050
3044
3010
3058
3079
2990
3006
2943
2874
2825
2858
2907
2926
2853
2874
2990
2981
3082
3080
3046
3002
3010
3075
3046
3002
3050
3019
2935
2972
2937
2823
2711
2751
1535
2820
2777
2823
2955
2975
2935
3037
3050
3002
3044
3066
3010
2999
3043
3080
3079
2987
2990
3020
2970
3094
3043
3063
3005
3035
3036
2982
2940
2954
2916
2939
2895
2838
2777
2727
2803
1535
2818
2709
2777
2898
2898
2939
2918
3014
2940
2997
3045
3035
3014
3066
3043
3099
2971
3020
3029
2994
3053
3051
3019
2983
2935
2981
2987
2905
2948
2897
2838
2859
2714
2784
2751
2845
1535
2929
2835
2784
2777
2868
2838
2907
2939
2905
2979
2978
2935
2968
3019
3051
3035
3009
3029
3054
3003
2941
2934
2972
2975
2942
2887
2948
2906
2849
2896
2825
2711
2742
2793
2862
2916
1535
2919
2862
2793
2754
2777
2825
2911
2845
2906
2939
2883
2942
2975
2999
2934
2948
3003
3054
2940
2885
3009
2972
2916
2864
2939
2914
2890
2844
2832
2822
2777
2693
2727
2820
2824
2886
1535
2883
2818
2820
2724
2711
2777
2828
2898
2844
2898
2930
2939
2872
2921
2972
3014
2886
2940
2979
2961
2885
2884
2955
2929
2910
2850
2815
2850
2801
2714
2714
2797
2810
2805
2918
2922
1535
2931
2918
2805
2798
2797
2714
2777
2789
2850
2812
2843
2910
2932
2948
2884
2882
2961
2979
2905
2873
2943
2929
2897
2888
2838
2911
2862
2816
2723
2741
2784
2791
2751
2895
2851
2872
1535
2950
2929
2895
2820
2740
2784
2675
2777
2816
2868
2890
2838
2876
2904
2929
2939
2881
2905
2939
2932
2949
2896
2855
2821
2820
2842
2810
2777
2693
2739
2730
2810
2776
2821
2890
2857
1535
2857
2881
2821
2788
2801
2730
2736
2702
2777
2822
2830
2820
2809
2852
2896
2942
2926
2939
2906
2893
2836
2832
2896
2862
2825
2813
2720
2708
2733
2701
2793
2754
2862
2878
2913
2873
1535
2870
2919
2878
2862
2820
2793
2698
2754
2708
2777
2810
2825
2862
2911
2832
2845
2905
2906
2886
2858
2811
2903
2859
2807
2822
2717
2705
2716
2782
2741
2810
2770
2868
2932
2945
2832
1535
2814
2939
2932
2859
2764
2810
2738
2776
2716
2696
2777
2822
2822
2856
2903
2868
2852
2886
2844
2815
2883
2859
2822
2807
2777
2702
2714
2706
2712
2804
2820
2813
2824
2914
2895
2742
1535
2745
2883
2914
2815
2825
2820
2801
2724
2706
2711
2708
2777
2810
2831
2859
2898
2812
2844
2887
2856
2803
2816
2825
2720
2696
2702
2736
2695
2761
2819
2759
2865
2861
2887
2887
2683
1535
2689
2878
2887
2849
2856
2759
2819
2764
2695
2748
2708
2696
2777
2828
2816
2806
2865
2887
2859
2827
2798
2816
2711
2702
2717
2733
2797
2738
2798
2760
2802
2889
2903
2939
2916
2750
1535
2729
2916
2939
2906
2886
2802
2835
2792
2738
2797
2742
2717
2714
2777
2816
2846
2839
2859
2822
2813
2844
2777
2708
2720
2745
2786
2712
2784
2795
2771
2859
2815
2926
2922
2941
2768
1535
2774
2953
2922
2938
2821
2859
2771
2816
2784
2718
2789
2745
2702
2702
2777
2831
2813
2822
2816
2807
2723
2717
2741
2734
2784
2745
2791
2837
2760
2835
2895
2888
2851
2972
2872
2705
1535
2783
2950
2972
2914
2831
2895
2769
2820
2837
2740
2754
2784
2692
2732
2717
2777
2816
2816
2801
2723
2699
2699
2725
2733
2698
2741
2790
2813
2756
2839
2769
2875
2870
2846
2840
2704
1535
2716
2858
2846
2882
2890
2769
2848
2762
2813
2793
2738
2698
2751
2725
2699
2702
2777
2801
2777
2696
2702
2708
2739
2785
2730
2784
2807
2820
2761
2859
2821
2944
2890
2892
2860
2743
1535
2731
2857
2892
2902
2935
2821
2862
2788
2820
2801
2781
2730
2773
2745
2708
2702
2687
2777


Could you please provide some data for testing? And maybe also your gnuplot script? Then we don't have to start from scratch. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@theozh Ok, trying to get the data size down so that it is appropriate for here. Problem is that when I reduce the number of data points, then the artifact goes (mostly) away. Is there a place where I can put that stuff?

@theozh added a script to my question and a cat of x.data.

thanks for adding data (and script). Yes, that's why I ask for data to really reproduce the problem and test a solution. Currently, I don't see any other solution than the one in the answer you linked. And note the disclaimer there: no testing without data. You have to do this procedure for all your different files.

Problem solved? Question answered?

As far as I understand, the "solution" is to enhance the Gnuplot implementation and use an updated Gnuplot version?

Ok. Since you have been asking now, I assumed you want a solution or a workaround now. But if this it is not urgent then you can wait until the feature request might be implemented in a new gnuplot version. No idea how long that might take.

As for the approach proposed below, that does not scale. When there are many points with same y then the point size has to be set so small that the points are vanishing.

which approach do you mean? Ethan's or mine? In my approach you don't set a point size but a linewidth.

For point of reference set style boxplot nooutliers does not affect the calculation of quartiles or other properties.  It is simply a flag that tells the program to skip the step of drawing a symbol for each outlier. This has the sometimes unwanted side effect that the outliers still contribute to autoscaling on the y axis even though they are not drawn.
Outliers are spread horizontally by the width of the pointsize of the current plot.  So you can shrink the spacing by reducing the point size:
set style boxplot outliers pointtype 7
set style data boxplot
plot $DAT using (1):2, $DAT using (2):2 pointsize 0.5



I tried this, but when I set the pointsize to 0 then the points will disappear. Is there a way to set the size to 0 without scaling the points?

I can think of several things that ought to work, but they don't. I will open a bug report or feature request that with boxplot should accept character point types (it doesn't now) and that outlier separation should be affected by set jitter (works for other plot styles but not for boxplot).   By the way - adding the "nooutliers" keyword only turns off drawing the outliers; it does not change calculation of the quartiles or other statistics.

Here is a suggestion to customize the width of the outliers. It basically uses the principle from this answer.

use stats to do statistics and determine the quartiles
count the outliers per y-value (via smooth freq) in datablock $OUTLIERS
instead of plotting horizontally distributed points or a number, plot a horizontal line with a length proportional to the number of points. This line can be scaled with the maximum number of outliers to fit the boxplot boxwidth and can also be scaled in thickness via linewidth.

Just for illustration, I added some more outliers (3x at 1000, 10x at 2000 and 5x at 2500).
One (strange) observation: If you do autoscale the y-range will be set to [0:3500], but the single outlier at 61 will not be displayed. I don't understand why. Is it clipping of datapoints close to the border or a bug? If you set the y-range, e.g. to [-100:] it will be displayed.
Data: SO78607023.dat
1000
1000
1000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2500
2500
2500
2500
2500
2806
2812
2825
2849
2901
2840
2894
2923
2944
2879
2977
2939
3068
3016
3018
2994
2891
1629
2873
2997
3018
3034
3053
2939
2986
2912
2944
2918
2891
2840
2883
2861
2825
2812
2797
2887
2816
2887
2819
2815
2841
2864
2818
2848
2898
2944
2871
2963
2896
3005
3017
2981
2989
2837
1629
2852
2986
2981
2993
3008
2896
2966
2871
2944
2891
2860
2818
2852
2827
2815
2803
2836
2816
2819
2815
2887
2847
2849
2862
2885
2858
2898
2956
2884
2944
3016
3006
2986
3093
3015
2862
1629
2928
3087
3093
3058
2952
3016
2890
2950
2956
2848
2813
2885
2805
2794
2847
2836
2812
2819
2821
2818
2843
2887
2822
2836
2855
2896
2829
2894
2913
2889
2983
2940
3050
3048
3073
2902
1629
2914
3079
3048
3056
2939
2983
2896
2940
2894
2828
2905
2855
2812
2812
2887
2836
2816
2821
2859
2844
2845
2821
2887
2830
2818
2853
2910
2857
2909
2944
2923
2998
3033
3062
3054
2893
1629
2872
3045
3062
3031
2977
2923
2953
2902
2857
2898
2855
2818
2828
2830
2821
2860
2844
2859
2904
2867
2869
2839
2833
2887
2803
2827
2858
2817
2880
2943
2862
2981
2982
3016
3016
2838
1629
2826
3007
3016
2995
2980
2862
2934
2895
2817
2865
2809
2803
2839
2815
2839
2847
2850
2904
2843
2814
2888
2858
2828
2813
2887
2818
2831
2822
2829
2914
2944
2931
2948
3040
3021
2882
1629
2879
3015
3040
2933
2949
2944
2917
2834
2822
2821
2818
2887
2809
2837
2858
2903
2817
2843
2901
2851
2868
2903
2849
2830
2821
2887
2818
2844
2889
2846
2919
2906
2989
3041
3074
2951
1629
2963
3074
3041
2986
2885
2919
2857
2913
2844
2815
2836
2821
2815
2852
2903
2858
2854
2901
2926
2897
2905
2825
2917
2865
2827
2821
2887
2812
2855
2805
2888
2884
2989
2993
3042
3001
1629
3010
3057
2993
2986
2960
2888
2811
2858
2812
2839
2818
2827
2849
2910
2825
2908
2909
2926
2947
2940
2959
2897
2860
2820
2825
2847
2815
2887
2803
2849
2840
2926
2894
2939
3016
2991
1629
2997
3013
2939
2912
2918
2840
2850
2812
2887
2825
2829
2825
2815
2855
2897
2954
2940
2947
2880
2874
2891
2916
2908
2883
2825
2892
2858
2806
2887
2783
2835
2910
2881
2965
2983
3012
1629
3084
3049
2965
2960
2847
2835
2803
2836
2806
2853
2895
2825
2880
2917
2916
2881
2883
2880
2976
2962
2943
2896
2947
2946
2917
2845
2808
2859
2779
2887
2818
2907
2917
2923
3033
3054
1629
3045
3024
2923
2902
2898
2818
2834
2860
2859
2821
2854
2917
2947
2881
2896
2948
2952
2976
2934
2891
3012
2978
2919
2865
2947
2929
2891
2843
2831
2828
2887
2809
2843
2944
2948
3018
1629
3015
2942
2944
2834
2821
2887
2827
2903
2843
2906
2931
2947
2880
2915
2978
3008
2889
2934
3063
3000
3001
2928
2993
2972
2930
2901
2891
2929
2913
2910
2812
2887
2859
2900
2977
3033
1629
3048
2977
2900
2861
2831
2812
2916
2908
2929
2875
2883
2930
2984
3002
2928
3001
2988
3063
3017
3012
2985
3045
3022
2977
2943
2984
2978
2889
2884
2920
2846
2858
2887
2834
2944
2983
1629
3046
2944
2834
2834
2855
2846
2923
2878
2889
2979
2988
2943
2978
3016
3045
2972
2998
3017
3017
2976
3088
3043
3057
3011
3035
3036
2988
2934
2960
2919
2947
2910
2844
2887
2843
2927
1629
2942
2823
2887
2903
2906
2947
2924
3008
2934
2991
3051
3035
3008
3060
3043
3093
2974
3017
2995
2984
3010
3069
3049
3011
3016
3063
3043
3017
2984
3022
2943
2966
2947
2846
2887
2887
1629
2944
2830
2846
2878
2979
2943
3035
2972
3017
3034
3066
3016
3014
3044
3069
3007
2969
2995
2886
2832
2851
2903
2894
2833
2877
2952
2990
2986
3001
3055
3007
3029
2979
2922
2890
2887
1629
2821
2872
2922
2972
3037
3007
3043
3001
2986
3002
2965
2877
2818
2885
2903
2842
2841
2886
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
61
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
1632
2874
2847
2929
2907
2861
2821
2874
2952
3005
2990
3079
3046
3010
3037
3047
2935
2937
2708
1535
2777
2939
2935
3050
3044
3010
3058
3079
2990
3006
2943
2874
2825
2858
2907
2926
2853
2874
2990
2981
3082
3080
3046
3002
3010
3075
3046
3002
3050
3019
2935
2972
2937
2823
2711
2751
1535
2820
2777
2823
2955
2975
2935
3037
3050
3002
3044
3066
3010
2999
3043
3080
3079
2987
2990
3020
2970
3094
3043
3063
3005
3035
3036
2982
2940
2954
2916
2939
2895
2838
2777
2727
2803
1535
2818
2709
2777
2898
2898
2939
2918
3014
2940
2997
3045
3035
3014
3066
3043
3099
2971
3020
3029
2994
3053
3051
3019
2983
2935
2981
2987
2905
2948
2897
2838
2859
2714
2784
2751
2845
1535
2929
2835
2784
2777
2868
2838
2907
2939
2905
2979
2978
2935
2968
3019
3051
3035
3009
3029
3054
3003
2941
2934
2972
2975
2942
2887
2948
2906
2849
2896
2825
2711
2742
2793
2862
2916
1535
2919
2862
2793
2754
2777
2825
2911
2845
2906
2939
2883
2942
2975
2999
2934
2948
3003
3054
2940
2885
3009
2972
2916
2864
2939
2914
2890
2844
2832
2822
2777
2693
2727
2820
2824
2886
1535
2883
2818
2820
2724
2711
2777
2828
2898
2844
2898
2930
2939
2872
2921
2972
3014
2886
2940
2979
2961
2885
2884
2955
2929
2910
2850
2815
2850
2801
2714
2714
2797
2810
2805
2918
2922
1535
2931
2918
2805
2798
2797
2714
2777
2789
2850
2812
2843
2910
2932
2948
2884
2882
2961
2979
2905
2873
2943
2929
2897
2888
2838
2911
2862
2816
2723
2741
2784
2791
2751
2895
2851
2872
1535
2950
2929
2895
2820
2740
2784
2675
2777
2816
2868
2890
2838
2876
2904
2929
2939
2881
2905
2939
2932
2949
2896
2855
2821
2820
2842
2810
2777
2693
2739
2730
2810
2776
2821
2890
2857
1535
2857
2881
2821
2788
2801
2730
2736
2702
2777
2822
2830
2820
2809
2852
2896
2942
2926
2939
2906
2893
2836
2832
2896
2862
2825
2813
2720
2708
2733
2701
2793
2754
2862
2878
2913
2873
1535
2870
2919
2878
2862
2820
2793
2698
2754
2708
2777
2810
2825
2862
2911
2832
2845
2905
2906
2886
2858
2811
2903
2859
2807
2822
2717
2705
2716
2782
2741
2810
2770
2868
2932
2945
2832
1535
2814
2939
2932
2859
2764
2810
2738
2776
2716
2696
2777
2822
2822
2856
2903
2868
2852
2886
2844
2815
2883
2859
2822
2807
2777
2702
2714
2706
2712
2804
2820
2813
2824
2914
2895
2742
1535
2745
2883
2914
2815
2825
2820
2801
2724
2706
2711
2708
2777
2810
2831
2859
2898
2812
2844
2887
2856
2803
2816
2825
2720
2696
2702
2736
2695
2761
2819
2759
2865
2861
2887
2887
2683
1535
2689
2878
2887
2849
2856
2759
2819
2764
2695
2748
2708
2696
2777
2828
2816
2806
2865
2887
2859
2827
2798
2816
2711
2702
2717
2733
2797
2738
2798
2760
2802
2889
2903
2939
2916
2750
1535
2729
2916
2939
2906
2886
2802
2835
2792
2738
2797
2742
2717
2714
2777
2816
2846
2839
2859
2822
2813
2844
2777
2708
2720
2745
2786
2712
2784
2795
2771
2859
2815
2926
2922
2941
2768
1535
2774
2953
2922
2938
2821
2859
2771
2816
2784
2718
2789
2745
2702
2702
2777
2831
2813
2822
2816
2807
2723
2717
2741
2734
2784
2745
2791
2837
2760
2835
2895
2888
2851
2972
2872
2705
1535
2783
2950
2972
2914
2831
2895
2769
2820
2837
2740
2754
2784
2692
2732
2717
2777
2816
2816
2801
2723
2699
2699
2725
2733
2698
2741
2790
2813
2756
2839
2769
2875
2870
2846
2840
2704
1535
2716
2858
2846
2882
2890
2769
2848
2762
2813
2793
2738
2698
2751
2725
2699
2702
2777
2801
2777
2696
2702
2708
2739
2785
2730
2784
2807
2820
2761
2859
2821
2944
2890
2892
2860
2743
1535
2731
2857
2892
2902
2935
2821
2862
2788
2820
2801
2781
2730
2773
2745
2708
2702
2687
2777

Script:
### boxplot with customized width for outliers
reset session

FILE = "SO78607023.dat"

stats FILE u 1 nooutput
range      = 1.5     # default value of `set style boxplot range` value
rangeOut   = range*(STATS_up_quartile - STATS_lo_quartile)
outLow     = STATS_lo_quartile - rangeOut
outHigh    = STATS_up_quartile + rangeOut

outCheck(y) = y<outLow || y>outHigh
set table $OUTLIERS
    plot FILE u 1:(outCheck($1)) smooth freq
unset table
stats $OUTLIERS u 2 nooutput
boxWidth = 0.7
outWidth = boxWidth/STATS_max * 1.0

set boxwidth boxWidth
set xtic 1
set key noautotitle
set yrange[-100:]

set multiplot layout 1,2

    set style boxplot outliers
    plot FILE u (0):1 w boxplot pt 6 ps 1 lc "red", \

    set style boxplot nooutliers
    plot FILE u (0):1 w boxplot lc "web-green", \
        $OUTLIERS u (x=0,x-$2/2*outWidth):1:($2*outWidth):(0) w vec lw 3 lc "web-green" nohead

unset multiplot
#### end of script

Result:

